# how use json in javascript with django

Tags: javascript, django, json, d3.js

I am new in django and python
I'm trying use a json file in javascript using django

The Javascript works fine when I use without django
but when I do with django show me this error:

```
"TypeError: node is null"
```

I call the json this way:

```
d3.json("jsonfile.json", function(node) {
         ....
}
```

I tried to put the json in the templates dir with the html file and with js file but didn´t work

**Edit 1:**

```
d3.json("jsonfile.json", function(error, node) {
         ....
}
```

Shows me :
"TypeError: node is undefined"

All the js are in the same dir:

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/d3.v3.min.js" type= text/javascript></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL}}js/graph.js" type= "text/javascript"></script>
```

**Edit2:**

My JSON:

```
{  "coordinador":[    
    {"name":"ford","grupo":0},
    {"name":"user1","grupo":1},
    {"name":"user2","grupo":1},
    {"name":"user3","grupo":1},
    {"name":"car1","grupo":2},
    {"name":"car2","grupo":2},
    {"name":"car3","grupo":2},
    {"name":"car4","grupo":2},
    {"name":"car5","grupo":2}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"origen":"user1","objetivo":"ford"},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"origen":"user2","objetivo":"ford"},
    {"source":3,"target":0,"origen":"user3","objetivo":"ford"},
    {"source":4,"target":1,"origen":"car1","objetivo":"user1"},
    {"source":5,"target":1,"origen":"car2","objetivo":"user1"},
    {"source":6,"target":2,"origen":"car3","objetivo":"user2"},
    {"source":7,"target":2,"origen":"car4","objetivo":"user2"},
    {"source":8,"target":3,"origen":"car5","objetivo":"user3"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where are you putting this d3 code? Show us codes.

Comment: In the latest version, the second argument to the callback function is the actual data, i.e. try `d3.json("jsonfile.json", function(error, node) {...});`.

Comment: Hi.I tried but shows me now a different error: "TypeError: node is undefined"

Comment: What is the content of the file `jsonfile.json`?

Comment: re you sure the server path is correct?

Comment: I put the JSON in the same html directory(templates) and in the same js directory(static/js), and dont work

Comment: Oh finally! It was the dir whats was wrong. i was putting "d3.json("jsonfile.json")", when I should put all the url (/static/js/jsonfile.json)

Comment: Please consider answering your own question so the other people with the same problem can find the answer.

Comment: Yes, later. i still can't answer my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

As @Jason said, the problem was that the path was incorrect.

```
d3.json("/static/js/jsonfile.json", function(node) {
         ....
}
```

thanks for helping !!

Comment: You've saved my life!

Comment: Actually @Jason did :)